# Issues chaining scopes in Rails with context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, named-scope, scopes

I have 4 models: `Artists, Editions, Events & EventItems`.

- Editions have many Events
- Events have many Artists through EventItems
- Editions have many Artists through Events

On artists I have a scope `published`

I define active as an artists who is on an event which has a state which is NOT `draft`.

`scope :published, -> { joins(:events).where("events.state != ?", 'draft').uniq }`

This works fine until I start chaining them and want Artists who have at least on event which is `published` for a given edition.

`Edition.first.artists.published`

This works except that it will also joins `events` outside the current edition and wrongly publish artists if they have any events published (even if they are not in this particular edition).

To get it to work properly I had to hack it like so (which is horrible):

```
  scope :published, ->(edition = nil) {
    if edition.present?
      joins(:events).where("events.state != ? AND events.edition_id = ?", 'draft', edition.id).uniq
    else
      joins(:events).where("events.state != ?", 'draft').uniq
    end
  }
```

`Edition.first.artists.published(Edition.first)`

Is there anyway to give more context to the scope to only include those events in this edition?  So it will scope correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the problem relies on your associations and the SQL you're generating, not how you should provide context to a scope (passing an argument is perfectly legitimate).

When calling `Event.artists` you're already joining events with `has_many :artists, through: :events` and by that joining `events` indiscriminately. On top of that you are relying on events to determine if artists are active or not which is another source of confusion if not SRP violation.

I think the solution comes from defining the right associations :

```
class Edition
  has_many :events
  has_many :artists, through: :events

  has_many :active_events, -> {where.not(state: "draft")}, class_name: "Events"
  has_many :active_artists, through: :active_events, 
            class_name: "Artist", 
            source: :artists # => not sure if this option is necessary
end

class Events
  has_many :event_items
  has_many :artists, through: :event_items
end 

Event.first.active_artists
```

I am not 100% sure about the macros options but you get the idea.